# SSIS: How to Update Dates via a Transformation for Sundays and Holidays

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is the best way in SSIS and which transformation(s) should I use to change (update) dates from Sundays to the previous Friday with the exception of the 1st day of the month. The exception would then do an Update to change the date to Monday.

I would also then need an update to change dates that are on certain Holidays like Thanksgiving and Christmas to the previous day, unless of course that day is a Sunday.

I know how to find these dates using SQL, but I'm somewhat of a newbie in SSIS and not sure how this works using transformations or what the best method would be.

For reference, using SQL I use this to identify the dates within a month that are Sundays. I then do an update to change those to either Fridays, or like I said, if that causes it go outside of the current month to Mondays:

```
SELECT * FROM DriverRoutes 
where [Date] BETWEEN dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,'1/1/2014')-1,0) 
AND dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, '1/1/2014'), 0))
and DATEPART(w,[Date]) = '1' 

update DriverRoutes 
set DATEPART(w,[Date]) = '6'
where DATEPART(w,[Date]) = '1'
```

etc.... And then I also change dates manually when they are on Holidays, but don't want to do that each month anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A script task/component is going to be the SSIS tool you want for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calendar table that holds a list of dates and their business meanings.  The dates that are recognized locally as holidays, and the holidays that are recognized by a business are in constant flux.  Instead of embedded formulas, you end up with easy-to-read code.

```
UPDATE t1
SET [DeliveryDate] = t2.[NextBusinessDay]
FROM DriverRoutes t1
INNER JOIN Calendar t2 ON (t1.[Date] = t2.[Date])
WHERE t2.[IsHoliday] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Anon, for that solution, and this makes sense to me from the SQL query standpoint.  However, how/where do I do this in a transformation in an SSIS package?

Comment: Use the "Execute SQL" script task

Comment: Thanks again, Anon, and billinkc on those responses!  I have changed an existing table that includes dates with those columns for IsSunday and IsHoliday, and set all of the appropriate days to '1' just now.  So that worked well - Thanksgiving was a little tricky, but I got it figured out.

Comment: And so yes, I'll try Execute SQL script task; however, not sure where that is or how it will update the values when I actually do the load yet.  Like I said, I'm a newbie.  = )

Comment: Oh! I think I see it now.  I'm using data flow task - I need to select a Execute SQL task - my bad.  Still working on it...

Comment: To both of those that responded, the Execute SQL Task is working great! Thx!  And Anon, the two columns for IsSunday and Holiday is a tremendous help. All I had to do was add those columns in an existing table and then put the logic in the task that updates that table.